# Sort pandas dataframe column containing a list of floats

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, columnsorting

I have a Pandas dataframe looking like this:

| Class | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2.2 | Propellers |
| 4.1 | Solenoids |
| 4.10 | Barrels |
| 4.7 | Collagen |
| 4.9 | Beads |
| 5.5 | Prisms |

and I need to sort it in this format instead:

| Class | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2.2 | Propellers |
| 4.1 | Solenoids |
| 4.7 | Collagen |
| 4.9 | Beads |
| 4.10 | Barrels |
| 5.5 | Prisms |

I can do this in python but I was wondering if there is a way that I can do this easily in Pandas. I tried the regular sort but it considers the numbers as floats and therefore doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: If values are floats, why is sorted value `4.10` after `4.9` ? Because in floats `4.1` and `4.10` are same

Comment: Or need sorting strings naturally?

Comment: Exactly they get sorted like this by Pandas because they are floats. But I want them to be sorted the other way so I actually want "4.10" to be after "4.9" and I don't know how to do it...

Comment: It is possible only if use strings, with floats not possible